# Find a file with unknown extension

Tags: php, file, search

I got in my directory some images, with id in their names. I know the id's , but I don't know their formats, so I cant use a `href` to display them since I don't know the format.

I need an idea or function for this so I can search:

fe. `href="img/avatar/avatar_of_" . $id . ".EXT"`

If the file with image extension is found, then it'll display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use [`file_exists`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) to check if the file's there.

Build an array of "image extensions" and figure out which one the file exists for.

```
$exts = array('bmp','png','jpg');
foreach($exts as $ext) {
    if(file_exists("img/avatar/avatar_of_" . $id . "." . $ext)){
        $path = "img/avatar/avatar_of_" . $id . "." . $ext;
    }
}
```

Or, you could rename the file and convert it to a common extension.

Or, you could store somewhere what the extension for any given user's avatar is.

Comment: Thanks, nice nick name btw. `:p`

Answer (score 2):

i don't know is this what you want:

```
if(file_exists("img/avatar/avatar_of_" . $id . ".jpg")) {
    // display
}
```

or maybe:

```
foreach (glob("img/avatar/avatar_of_$id.*") as $filename) {
    //display
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does [glob](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) work for you? It lets you do a wildcard search.

Comment: I've rather thinking for a preg_math - search for image which format is in (PNG|JPG|JPEG|GIF) , if found - add an ext. to the variable , and then I can prepare image href.

Comment: `glob("{*.PNG,*.JPG,*.JPEG,*.GIF}", GLOB_BRACE)`

Comment: `var_dump(glob("./img/avatar/avatar_of_" . $id . ".*"));` , why it does return empty array? The file is there...